# Replace/Mute/Stop Search Query

Tags: database, query, search, pre-get-posts, search-engines

I'm trying to replace the search functionality in WP.

I've already created the `search.php` template with all the results I want to display.

I don't want any results from the WP database.
I just want to show my results in `search.php` using the native `searchform.php` and the native `?s=keyword` URL structure.

Doing that because of `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts ...` search built in query with is very CPU consuming.

So in my themes functions.php I added:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'no_search_query');
function no_search_query($query) {
    if($query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && get_query_var('s', false)) {
        unset( $query->query_vars['s'] );
        $query->set( 'post__in', '' );
    }
}
```

and added:

```
$is_search_query = ($_GET["s"]) ? ($_GET["s"]) : 0;
```

to my search.php to get the search keyword.

This actually did the trick but the query is still being called.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ...
```

The call to the database is now a lot of less consuming (there are no arguments) but its still a call to the database which I want to eliminate.

Any idea how to do that?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick grep for SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and found a few instances. I'm not sure which one is being called in your case, but here's an interesting one from wp-includes/class-wp-query.php line 2904 onwards:

```
$found_rows = '';
if ( ! $q['no_found_rows'] && ! empty( $limits ) ) {
  $found_rows = 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS';
}

$old_request   = "SELECT $found_rows $distinct $fields FROM {$wpdb->posts} $join WHERE 1=1 $where $groupby $orderby $limits";
$this->request = $old_request;

if ( ! $q['suppress_filters'] ) {
  /**
   * Filters the completed SQL query before sending.
   *
   * @since 2.0.0
   *
   * @param string   $request The complete SQL query.
   * @param WP_Query $this    The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
   */
  $this->request = apply_filters_ref_array( 'posts_request', array( $this->request, &$this ) );
}
```

The important part is that there's a filter here where you get the SQL and you can do your own checks on it. It doesn't look like you can stop the query running, but at least you could change the SQL to something that doesn't bother you ;-)

I don't know what the suppress_filters flag is here, so you'll need to make sure that that isn't set.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your response. Any idea how to change the search SQL query before sending though?

Comment: Yes - if this is the place that your query is being called from you just need to implement this filter - it will let you change the SQL before it's run.

Comment: To what filter are you referring to? Am I missing something?

Comment: The last line in the code in my answer calls the filter `'posts_request'` - you just need to hook into that filter. Do you know how filters in WP work?